# getting js to fire after a div has been populated dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I am having a hard time getting the javascript to execute after the div #mcs4_container has been populated, it instead fires before any content has been loaded.  This is a piece of a processing page from a .post(), so unfortunately I cannot put it on (window).load because the window is already loaded. mCustomScrollbar is a jquery plugin that adds a scrollbar to the content included in mcs4_container.  Below is the relevant php:

```
echo
'<div id="reserveAPickupAppointmentForm6">';

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo
        'There are currently no appointments available online for this date.  Please call or email the office to set up a custom time.';
    }

    else {

        echo
        '<div id="mcs4_container">
        <div class="customScrollBox">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="content">';

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo
                '<div   class = "hoverLive2 reserveAPickupAppointmentDateText reserveAPickupAppointmentButtonText">'
                    .$row["date"].
                '</div>';
            }   

        echo
        '</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragger_container"><div class="dragger"></div></div>
        </div>
        </div>';

        echo
            '</div>';       

echo
'<script>
$("#mcs4_container").mCustomScrollbar("vertical",400,"easeOutCirc",1.05,"fixed","yes","yes",10);
</script>';

    }
```

Comment: Please don't output HTML like that; use templates.

Comment: sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean, and I'm also recovering from surgery on my right shoulder, so please bear with my one-handed typing.

Comment: Lol, that's fine (I hope you feel better soon). I mean that you're outputting HTML with echo commands; don't do that. You should use http://www.smarty.net/ (or any other template engine). Really cleans up your code.

Comment: I guess I dont know how else I can do it if I need a while loop in the middle.  Do you have any resources on this?

Comment: Yes, but, those aren't really related to this problem. Basically, you'd want to load this all up into a list, then pass that list into a template (no business logic in templates).

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post('/whatev', function() {//this is your callback});
```

If you're using jQuery, the above should give you a callback that fires when your post request is filled.

Not 100% sure if that's what you want.

Comment: hmm, I assume you mean adding this at the end of the post function that brings you to the processing page.   I couldn't get this to work earlier, but I will try again.

Comment: You put that callback thing after when you're calling the .post(), yes.

Comment: you should do some research on how callbacks work.  Even better in the context of asynchronous requests.  It's a pretty standard technique.

Comment: okay, I'll read up and get back to you guys.  Thanks for your help so far.